# error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker-errors

So in my project I am getting these link errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  
Error   2   error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)
Error   3   error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)
Error   4   error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)
Error   7   error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Now I remember getting these about a month back and through fiddling with additional dependencies and some other project properties I was able to get everything to compile (that's about all I remember). Now that I'm trying to convert my project to release mode I'm getting them again.

I have compared all the project properties from release to debug and made sure everything was the same except setting the runtime library to /MD instead of /MDd obviously. Both share all the same additional dependencies also.

Is there anything else I could be missing?

Comment: If you use 3rd party libraries make sure the use the same CRT as you are using.

Comment: @drescherjm all of my libraries are using /MD for the release version

Comment: You are, somehow, linking the C runtime library twice.  Pretty hard to do without generating additional linker warnings.  Maybe different copies of msvcrt.lib, bit of a stretch, add the /VERBOSE linker option to see where stuff is coming from.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20918729/17034