# Determine Why Lib File is Being Linked

Tags: visual-studio, hololens

I'm in the process of updating an older Hololens project to the latest version of Visual Studio, the latest Target Platform, and a newer version of C++.  We haven't done a build of this project in over a year, so we've also had many changes to our codebase (which is shared with our desktop version, so we are able to use a lot more libs than we can in Hololens).

I'm currently getting this error when compiling:
`LINK: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'comsuppwd.lib'`

Being a Hololens app, the comsuppw library isn't available. Is there a way to see what is causing this library to be included? I'm trying to avoid having to manually go through a years worth of changelists to find what is causing this library to be linked.

I've used dumpbin/undname to get a list of all of the public symbols in comsuppw.lib, and done a search for any we may have used (and found nothing).  I've also turned on verbose linking, but didn't see anything helpful.

Comment: Is your project type a holographic DirectX UWP project? To target HoloLens it should be a Universal Windows Platform app. Could you double-check the Link Setting to make sure the lib is configured correctly? Have you updated your VC++ version of your project? Also, could you provide the Visual Studio version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to track down the offending class by using dumpbin on all of the .obj files, using this command:

```
for /R %1 in (*.obj) do @dumpbin /directives /section:.drectve "%1" > "%1".directives.txt
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249431/linker-trouble-how-to-determine-where-a-defaultlib-is-coming-from?rq=1)